# How to get the html of td when click on checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `table`, something like the following

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRow(this)" value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function toggleRow(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    }
</script>
```

When I click on `td` I get the following outputs

```
<td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
```

and when I click on `checkbox`, i get the following output

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRow(this)" value="1" />
```

How can I get

```
<td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
```

when I click on `checkbox`?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want all the `td`s or a particular `td`?

Comment: @DragonBorn: a particular `td`, the nearest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse to closest td obj using `.closest` selector:

> closest:For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
function toggleRow(obj) {
    console.log($(obj).closest('td')[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function toggleRow(obj) {
    console.log($(obj).closest('td')[0]);
   }
</script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td onclick="toggleRow(this)">some text</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRow(this)" value="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: still gives the same output

Comment: @abbas: its logging td element if you click on checkbox. run the snippet above

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, it's giving the nearest `td`, but now clicking on `checkbox` doesn't check or unchecks it.

Comment: @abbas: it does in demo above. can you reproduce the problem in question snippet or fiddle

Comment: Yes, it is working, some other code in the `script` was disturbing it.